# Will I get performance gains from using a texture atlas with JavaFX Canvas and rendering sub-images?

Tags: java, javafx, canvas, textures, texture-atlas

I am developing a game using JavaFX for an assignment. I am familiar with texture atlases and the fact that they bring performance improvements (I've previously worked on similar projects using LibGDX). Does this apply to JavaFX's Canvas specifically?

In other words, is it worth making a texture atlas for my assets and using this single image instead of using a separate image for each asset? I am asking because I am unfamiliar with how Canvas and GraphicsContext is implemented.

If I did use a texture atlas, I would use the

```
writeImage(Image img, double dx, double dy, double dw, double dh, double sx, double sy, double sw, double sh)
```

method of GraphicsContext, which I assume is efficient.

Otherwise, I would have separate Image instances for each asset.

Comment: what about doing and measuring ;)

Comment: @kleopatra I surely will do that but I thought maybe someone either has experience with this or are knowledgeable enough about JavaFX's Canvas to be able to provide an answer without actually having to measure it at all.

Comment: If you already have some experience with LibGDX, wouldn't the use of the JavaFX MeshView make more sense than the canvas? In this case I would also tend to answer your question with yes although I have no definitive proof for this.